Airflow schedulers not triggered as expected when introducing the catchup=False and Max_active_runs=1
Below is my DAG configuration. Here, we introduce max_active_runs=1 to skip the next execution. Although I'm scheduling it for 2-minute cron intervals, it triggers the first three intervals within 2 minutes. After that, it triggers at 5-minute intervals, then 7-minute intervals, and so on. Occasionally, runs fail, and when I check the logs, it shows 'No existing session.
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import os
import sys
import paramiko
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
import pendulum

loc_tz = pendulum.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
default_args = {
          'start_date':datetime(2024,4,15,21,14, tzinfo=loc_tz),
          'end_date':datetime(2024,4,15,23,59, tzinfo=loc_tz),
          'owner':'Airflow',
          'provide_context':True
          }
dag = DAG('Added_0', description ='Simple bot file creation',schedule_interval ='*/2 * * * *',default_args=default_args,catchup=False,max_active_runs=1,is_paused_upon_creation=True)

bot_execution_task_main = SSHOperator(ssh_conn_id = 'Servertest', 
task_id = 'Added_0_bot_execution_task_main',
dag = dag,
command = 'java -cp /C:/Users/devshaded.jar AutomationAgent  <Config Beartoken>'
)

Output:
[Connectivity issue] (https://i.sstatic.net/IaGwW.png)
I am tried in reset the airflow db for clear all the sessions. and restart the airflow but there is no luck. But when I delete the max_active_runs=1 in dag it should work as expected.
I am using airflow 2.1.2
So, what my expectation is max_active_runs why its change the scheduler behavior.

Try looking at some of the popular questions on SSHExeception 6k views 3k views. However, we wouldn't have been able to find this error-message because it was posted as an image. Post stack-dumps and error-messages as text, so that other people can find them using search.
